# Gitblit: Bad Request when navigate to a second-level folder

Tags: git, gitblit

I am trying [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/), which seems quite a good web-UI for Git. The installation through the war file is pretty easy and works out-of-the-box. However, I am running into a strange issue.
I am sharing a Maven project which has a standard folder structure

```
project
   pom.xml
   src
   src/test-file.txt (I added this file to verify the issue)
   src/java
   src/java/main
   src/java/main/package
   src/java/main/package/File.java
```

As long as I try to navigate the first level (so, `pom.xml` and `src`) everything is fine, I can open and read the file correctly. However, when I try to open the folder `java` under `src`, the link is rendered as `localhost:8080/gitblit/tree/project/commit-id/src%2Fjava` and I am presented a white page. The request is not forwarded to the server (tomcat 7.0.32 if this can help) and firebug simply tells me `Error 400: Bad Request`.
That `%2F` looks weird, so I manually tried to fix the link in `localhost:8080/gitblit/tree/project/commit-id/src/java`, but then an internal server error is generated. Looking at the logs, I read

```
INFO  Found more URL path parts then expected, these will be ignored. Url: 'http://localhost:8080/gitblit/tree/project/commit-id/src/java', mountpath: 'blob', urlPath: 'project/commit-id/src/java', expected 3 parameters was 4
```

Then, I added that `test-file.txt`. If I navigate to `src` and try to open `test-file.txt`, firstly the link tries to open `localhost:8080/gitblit/blob/project/commit-id/src%2Ftest-file.txt`, presenting a html page stating that the file is not found. If I try the same trick as before (`%2F` to `/`), then I receive this Exception:

```
INFO  Found more URL path parts then expected, these will be ignored. Url: 'http://localhost:8080/gitblit/blob/project/commit-id/src/test-file.txt', mountpath: 'blob', urlPath: 'project/commit-id/src/test-file.txt', expected 3 parameters was 4
ERROR /path/to/project/.git cant find {1} in tree {2}
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.IncorrectObjectTypeException: Object commit-id is not a blob.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectDatabase.open(ObjectDatabase.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.open(Repository.java:278)
    at com.gitblit.utils.JGitUtils.getByteContent(JGitUtils.java:563)
    at com.gitblit.utils.JGitUtils.getStringContent(JGitUtils.java:596)
    at com.gitblit.wicket.pages.BlobPage.<init>(BlobPage.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor22.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:305)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1279)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1358)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1465)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
ERROR Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.gitblit.wicket.pages.BlobPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument r = "project" h = "commit-id" f = "src"
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.gitblit.wicket.pages.BlobPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument r = "project" h = "commit-id" f = "src"
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:305)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1279)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1358)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1465)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor22.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:188)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gitblit.wicket.pages.BlobPage.generateSourceView(BlobPage.java:142)
    at com.gitblit.wicket.pages.BlobPage.<init>(BlobPage.java:134)
    ... 31 more
```

I basically did not configure gitblit itself (no changes to `gitblit.properties`), so my problem could reside in a missed-configuration, but I could figure out where. Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> no changes to gitblit.properties

This sentence was the one causing the trouble. And the solution was really well documented on [Gitblit.com FAQ](http://gitblit.com/faq.html).

> Running Gitblit on Tomcat
>   Tomcat takes the extra precaution of [disallowing embedded slashes by default](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-6.html#Fixed_in_Apache_Tomcat_6.0.10). This breaks Gitblit urls.
>   You have a few options on how to handle this scenario:
>    1. **Tweak Tomcat**
>       Add -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true to CATALINA_OPTS or to your JVM launch parameters
>    2. **Modify gitblit.properties** using one of:
>    - web.mountParameters = false and use non-pretty, parameterized urls
>    - web.forwardSlashCharacter = ! which tells Gitblit to use ! instead of /

I used `web.forwardSlashCharacter = !`, reload gitblit webapp from the manager, and now everything works fine. My fault I did not carefully read the FAQs until [James Morger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830200/james-moger) suggested me the lecture.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to fix this stupid problem is to disable **Mount URL** in /var/lib/tomcat7/gitblit.properties:

**Follow this easy steps:**

1. nano /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/gitblit/WEB-INF/data/gitblit.properties
2. find web.mountParameters = true *and change to* **false**
3. restart tomcat **/etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart**
4. that's all !

Cya!